# Why SplPriorityQueue keys are reversed?

Tags: php

The following code:

```
$queue = new \SplPriorityQueue();
$queue->insert('a', 4);
$queue->insert('b', 3);
$queue->insert('d', 1);
$queue->insert('c', 2);
foreach($queue as $key => $value) {
  print "$key:$value\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
3:a 
2:b 
1:c 
0:d
```

Expected behavior:

```
0:a 
1:b 
2:c 
3:d
```

Is it bug or am I missing something?

Comment: internally `splPriorityQueue` is implemented as a numerical indexed array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why were you expecting numerical keys starting with 0?  Because that is what we are used to seeing with arrays.

For arrays counting upwards is ideal. However for a queue, especially a priority queue in which we are going to allow unknown priority insertions, a [max heap is ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). In reality, the key/value convention is merely applied when you begin removing items from the queue. It counts downwards to simulate max heap.

Natively, you'll get something closer to this: https://eval.in/96293

```
Array
(
    [data] => a
    [priority] => 9
)
Array
(
    [data] => b
    [priority] => 3
)
Array
(
    [data] => c
    [priority] => 2
)
Array
(
    [data] => d
    [priority] => 1
)
```

Which was created thus:

```
$queue->setExtractFlags(SplPriorityQueue::EXTR_BOTH); 
while($queue->valid()){ 
    print_r($queue->current()); 
    $queue->next(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over the priority queue with foreach and worrying about how the class stores data internally, try using the methods built into the SPLPriorityQueue class:

```
while($queue->valid()){ 
    print_r($queue->current()); 
    echo "<BR>"; 
    $queue->next(); 
}
```

(Modified example taken from user submission on php.net: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splpriorityqueue.php)

Comment: Queue implements Iterator interface so it can be traversed with foreach loop. This while loop pattern looks much more tedious.

Comment: @NikitaObukhov The `\SplPriorityQueue` implements `Iterator`, `Traversable`.